# How to deal with multiple currencies ED?

Tags: balances, existential-deposit

If I understand correctly, once anyone of the currency drop-down below the ED then the account will be killed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that when an account's balance drops below the existential deposit, its state is removed from the storage to not bloat up the precious on-chain storage. The handling of the remaining balance is up to the runtime configuration, most projects send it to the Treasury or burn it.

You could take a look at Basilisk's take on handling ED in a multi-asset environment which they presented during Sub0 2021 ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz1lfVyAKQ0)). They take multiple factors such as the current price and liquidity into account to determine the ED dynamically. Moreover, they showcase an off-chain duster.

A simple solution would be to map each asset `X1, ..., Xn` to a value of an asset `Y` hard-coded in the runtime and base your ED on `Y` such that the sum of all of your assets' translated values shall not fall below a certain threshold: `sum(Y(X1), ..., Y(Xn)) >= ED`.